# How to display a changing integer in a window?

Tags: java

I want to display a changing integer inside a window, but I can't figure it out.

I tried using the command

```
XPage.setText("Output:  " + Integer.toString(x));
```

(`XPage` being the label and `x` being the changing `int`), however this command doesn't show the integer until it is done changing.

Does anyone know how I could display the integer?

EDIT: My code, it makes any # you plug into it go to 50.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
  //String converted to an int
  String input = textfield.getText();
  int x = Integer.parseInt(input);

  //int turned to 50
  while (x<50||x>50) {
    //Sleep
    try{
      Thread.sleep(250);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie){
      //Log message if required.
    }
    XPage.setText("Output:  " + Integer.toString(x));
    System.out.println("Output:  "+x);
    if (x<50) {
      x++;
    }
    if (x>50) {
      x--;
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Output:  "+x);
  XPage.setText("Output:  " + Integer.toString(x));
}
```

Comment: At least provide a [mcve] and a detailed description of what you are trying to achieve, together with the problem description/error. Read through [ask] and [help], thanks.

Comment: Post your code, we can only guess, but my guess is you only set the integer the once to be the XPage Text, as for the output text, just use `Xpage.setText("Output: " + Integer.toString(x))`, or just +x

Comment: Thanks Zack6849, this did allow me to have "Output: " on the window. I also edited my post to show my code.